# Functional mobile redirects: PC to mobile for mobile user and mobile to PC (for PC)

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, user-agent

I want to do this: Somebody share my mobile page on Facebook. For example, click that link of sharing.. But this user used to PC, not mobile.

If coming from the PC to the mobile page, that people are redirected to the desktop page.

My htaccess code (mobile page):

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Could you?

Comment: so what does not work?

Comment: I have run into this error: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Comment: Do you have any other Rewrite rules in htaccess?

Comment: Yes:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Note you don't need the www to non www redirect in your htaccess, just 1 Rule is enough to remove  www and change  http to https.